# How do I make params available to all screens in a stack in react navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

A user clicks to navigate to a screen in a stack, which is also a stack. How do I pass a param that is available to the initial screen, into the entire stack?

```
const aStack = createStackNavigator({
DefaultScreen: DefaultScreen,

NavigatorScreen: {
    screen: ATabNavigator,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
      const id = navigation.state.params.id
      return {
        headerTitle: <Header id={id}  />,
        headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#f6f6f6'},
        headerLeft: null
      }
    }
  },

})
```

So when someone clicks on a link I set up previously they go to `navigation.navigate('NavigatorScreen', {id: 1})`

This makes `id` available to NavigatorScreen, which I use to pass in to my Header component, but then how do I pass that id to the ATabNavigator so that all screens in the tab navigator have access to it?

Comment: Instead of trying to figure out how to do this, I created a Redux action and set the state with the data I need onPress. Then in each screen I simply connect to the store and get the data I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the params you want in the screen initially like the following

```
DefaultScreen.navigationOptions = {
  id: 1
};
```

Then you can find the value in any screen

```
DefaultScreen.navigationOptions.id
```

Another way is to use state management stores like Mobx which allow you to share the values 
between all the screens and modify them as well
You can find more details in the link below:

https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx

Hopefully, this answers your question

Comment: or maybe just use `.getParam()`

Answer (score 0):

Use [.getParam()](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#getparam-get-a-specific-param-value-with-a-fallback) to get a specific param value with a fallback.

In your `NavigatorScreen` get the value like

```
const id = this.props.navigation.getParam('id', 'fallback value here');
```

Or get the value in `navigationOptions` like

```
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {

  const id = navigation.state.params.id;

}
```

[Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/get-params-from-navigator)